# Элементы GridView наезжают друг на друга

Tags: android, gridview

Возникла необходимость сделать GridView, однако у некоторых элементов бывает разная высота и при этом получается, что элементы наезжают друг на друга. Как можно исправить это?

```
     <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridViewCategory"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:columnWidth="80dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
            android:numColumns="4"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:verticalSpacing="5dp">

        </GridView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gridview не позволит вам изменять положение елементов относительно сетки, независимо от  того где заканчивается елемент над ним. Скорей всего вам нужно использовать recycler view и StaggeredGridLayoutManager

Пример:
http://www.devexchanges.info/2016/07/android-tip-staggered-grid-view-by.html?m=1

Answer (score 0):

У меня была похожая проблема, у меня текст из TextView начинался на том же пикселе, что и ImageView. Решил проблему тем, что просто привязал TextView к низу ImageView в xml файле в Design